# .bat file to open a specific folder and copy files from a usb drive

Tags: batch-file, usb

I am having difficulties with creating a simple batch file.

What I would like is a batch file that will open up a specific directory and copy 2 files from the same directory that the batch file is in and paste them in the directory that was just opened.

So, in this instance, I have a USB flash drive.  I have two *IE shortcuts* that I would like copied and placed in a public desktop.

The `.bat` file and the 2 files will all be on the root of the flash drive.

So, my understanding is that it should look like this (EWQ is the *IE shortcut* and *keyfinder* is just a test file because i wasn't sure on the extensions... i could not figure out what the *IE shortcut extension* would be as I don't think it has one):

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe C:\Users\Public\Desktop<br>
copy EWQ C:\Users\Public\Desktop<br>
copy keyfinder.cfg C:\Users\Public\Desktop
```

> I get my public desktop folder to open but nothing copies.  I have
>   tried various prefixes, like "%~dp0\EWQ" (with an without the quotes)
>   but to no avail.

These will be loaded from a *flash drive* and I have about 500 to do so I'd like this as quick and possible.  Basically, `pop` in the flash drive, double click the `.bat` file and yank it out.  In theory, it 'should' be the same drive letter every time, but that isn't guaranteed.

Thank you for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a batch file, let's call it **testing.cmd**.

```
@Copy "%~d0\EWQ.url" "%PUBLIC%\Desktop"
@Copy "%~d0\keyfinder.cfg" "%PUBLIC%\Desktop"
```

Place this file somewhere on your flash drive and double click it, ensuring that both **EWQ.url** and **keyfinder.cfg** are in the root of that drive. If you do not have access to the destination you could try by **right clicking** testing.cmd and choosing **Run as administrator**.

Comment: Hello,thank you for your answer.  I tried your suggestion, (copied and pasted your answer) but it didn't work. :(  I even tried without the  @  and it still did not work.

Comment: Are you allowed to copy items to the public desktop? Did you try running the batch file **as administrator** instead?

Comment: hello. I was just trying that. I am logged in with my admin account. It still does not copy.  At the moment, the files are not on my flash drive, they're just in a folder on my desktop... that shouldn't matter, correct?

Comment: Of course it should matter, if the files aren't currently on your flash drive then copy them to the root of your system drive i.e. **C:** and test from there.

Comment: I didn;t think it would matter because my files were in the same folder on my desktop.  I did as i intended, put them on a root of a flash drive, but still nothing.  I even switched the public directory to my current username, C:\users\MYuserNameHERE but that didn't work either.

Comment: In order for me to provide any further help, please edit you question by adding some additions. Such as the actual names of all of the files you are hoping to copy, their location paths including drive letters and the exact content of your batch file complete with it's name.

Comment: Just to verify, being logged with an admin account does not necessarily give you write access to the **Public Desktop**, it is most likely you will need to **right click** and **Run as administrator** as previously instructed.